# PHP password_verify on fetched hashed data from database

Tags: php, database, pdo, passwords, verification

I'm receiving this error:

> Notice: Undefined index: passwordLog in line 60.

Line 60:

```
if (password_verify($passwordLog,$row['password'])) {
```

I am using PDO.

```
if (isset( $_POST['btnLog'])) {

    $usernameLog = $_POST['usernameLog'];
    $passwordLog = $_POST['passwordLog'];

    $selectQuery = $connection->prepare("SELECT * FROM ".$table." WHERE username = :usernameLog");
    $selectQuery->execute(array(':usernameLog' => $usernameLog));

    $row = $selectQuery->fetchAll();       

    if($selectQuery->rowCount() > 0 )
    { 
        if (password_verify($passwordLog,$row['passwordLog'])) {
                header('Location: sample.html');
        }
        else
        {
            echo '<script>alert("Invalid Username/Password");</script>';
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo "<script>alert('Invalid Username or Password. Try again');</script>";
    }

}
```

Comment: Is the table column that holds your hashed password called `passwordLog`? Looks like it is not, maybe its just called `password`

Comment: Are you sure that `$table` has a value? Or rather the correct value? We cannot tell from your code

Comment: Please read [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
 and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @RiggsFolly or `passwordlog` all in lowercase. But we won't know that till they post their schema.

Comment: Good point @Fred-ii- _How the divil are you squire_

Comment: @RiggsFolly Moy-tee good, hope the same for you :-)

Comment: Like the new `meme` ( pun intended ) @Fred-ii-

Comment: my table column is password. even though i changed that $row['passwordLog'] to  $row['password'] , it still gives me the same error. and yes $table has a value of my table in database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok if the column name is fixed then the next issue is that you did a `fetchAll` which returns an array of rows and therefore the reference to the first result row would be

```
$row = $selectQuery->fetchAll();       

if($selectQuery->rowCount() > 0 )
{ 
    if (password_verify($passwordLog,$row[0]['password'])) {
                // code changed here     ^^^
        header('Location: sample.html');
    }
    else
    {
        echo '<script>alert("Invalid Username/Password");</script>';
    }
}
```

But as you are only expecting one row to be returned, or at least you have not coded to expect more than one row, using `->fetch()` would make more sence, like this

```
$row = $selectQuery->fetch();       

if($selectQuery->rowCount() > 0 )
{ 
    if (password_verify($passwordLog,$row['password'])) {
            header('Location: sample.html');
    }
    else
    {
        echo '<script>alert("Invalid Username/Password");</script>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @RiggsFolly! I appreaciate it. Btw, I'm sorry I wasn't that clear when providing information.

Comment: It seems I've fallen onto deaf ears.

Comment: ce la vie mon ami

Comment: I was into code immediately, my apologies. I marked checked already.